# How to upload a file with ajax in small chunks and check for fails, re-upload the parts that failed.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a file uploaded by a user, and I'd like to achieve the following.

1. Divide the file into smaller chunks about a megabyte.
2. Upload each chunk, and wait for it to finish before starting to upload the next chunk.
3. For every chunk get success or failure report.
4. Re-upload the failed chunks.
5. Get progress in percentages.

Here's some rough JavaScript. I'm literally lost. Got some code online and tried modifying it.

```
$.chunky = function(file, name){        
                var loaded = 0;
                var step = 1048576//1024*1024;
                var total = file.size;
                var start = 0;
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e){

                var d = {file:reader.result}
                $.ajax({
                    url:"../record/c/index.php",
                    type:"POST", 
                    data:d}).done(function(r){
                    $('.record_reply_g').html(r);

                    loaded += step;                 
                    $('.upload_rpogress').html((loaded/total) * 100);

                        if(loaded <= total){
                            blob = file.slice(loaded,loaded+step);
                            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
                        } else {
                            loaded = total;
                        }
                })              
                };

                var blob = file.slice(start,step);
                reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
            }
```

How can I achieve the above. Please do explain what's happening if there's a viable solution.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

Comment: not a bad start, you need to slice with an accumulated range, loaded will the the chunk size, and step seems to be constant... in general, try breaking the problem up into smaller peices, like something that can upload a range of data from a file, then a part that can call the ranged uploader on every part of a file, then a part to handle errors, then a part to announce "i'm done", ... in short, more small functions, less one big onload function.

Comment: @dandavis I have another function which can do chunks only, problem is waiting for each chunk to upload. its an array which contains chunks of about 1mb each.

Answer (score 10):

You are not doing anything for failure of any chunk upload.

```
$.chunky = function(file, name){        
    var loaded = 0;
    var step = 1048576//1024*1024; size of one chunk
    var total = file.size;  // total size of file
    var start = 0;          // starting position
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var blob = file.slice(start,step); //a single chunk in starting of step size
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);   // reading that chunk. when it read it, onload will be invoked

    reader.onload = function(e){            
        var d = {file:reader.result}
        $.ajax({
            url:"../record/c/index.php",
            type:"POST", 
            data:d                     // d is the chunk got by readAsBinaryString(...)
        }).done(function(r){           // if 'd' is uploaded successfully then ->
                $('.record_reply_g').html(r);   //updating status in html view

                loaded += step;                 //increasing loaded which is being used as start position for next chunk
                $('.upload_rpogress').html((loaded/total) * 100);

                if(loaded <= total){            // if file is not completely uploaded
                    blob = file.slice(loaded,loaded+step);  // getting next chunk
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);        //reading it through file reader which will call onload again. So it will happen recursively until file is completely uploaded.
                } else {                       // if file is uploaded completely
                    loaded = total;            // just changed loaded which could be used to show status.
                }
            })              
        };
}
```

**EDIT**

To upload failed chunk again you can do following :

```
var totalFailures = 0;
reader.onload = function(e) {
    ....
}).done(function(r){
    totalFailures = 0;
    ....
}).fail(function(r){   // if upload failed
   if((totalFailure++) < 3) { // atleast try 3 times to upload file even on failure
     reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
   } else {                   // if file upload is failed 4th time
      // show message to user that file uploading process is failed
   }
});
```

Comment: if(loaded <= total) if file is not completely uploaded, how is ajax uploading the rest of the file, shouldn't Ajax be called again to upload the rest of the file? And how can I check if a chunk failed?

Comment: when `reader.readAsBinaryString(blob)` is called then `reader.onload` is invoked again. So the file uploading is happening recursively.

Comment: ohhhhh ok ,makes sense, can we check for failure for each chunk?

Comment: isn't "var d = {file:reader.result}", uploading the whole file? isn't it suppose to be the "blob", which is a chunk?

Comment: `var d={file:reader.result}` is not uploading file. but is reading file, and only a chunk of it.

Comment: Ok, and shouddnt we put formData so that ajax can upload the files? Php doesn't get the files variables, only gets post vars.

Comment: In all language it is same. And here the data is being is sent with `"file"` as key (`var d = {file:reader.result}`)

Comment: No i mean this $_FILES['file'], since ajax doesn't support uploads unless we use something like "var formData = new formData();"     Now PHP doesn't seem to get any files.

Comment: Is the file in base64?

Comment: I think you'd want to include an 'id' and an 'index' for identifying & sequencing the chunks on the server too, unless it's a single user, single request system (unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

I've modified afzalex's answer to use `readAsArrayBuffer()`, and upload the chunk as a file.

```
    var loaded = 0;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var blob = file.slice(loaded, max_chunk_size);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('filedata', new File([reader.result], 'filechunk'));
      fd.append('loaded', loaded);
      $.ajax(url, {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        data: fd,
        processData: false
      }).done(function(r) {
        loaded += max_chunk_size;
        if (loaded < file.size) {
          blob = file.slice(loaded, loaded + max_chunk_size);
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        }
      });
    };
```