# How to upload a video in chunks Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, post, cloudflare

Im using Cloudflare, and it has a POST request limit of 100M and I want to upload larger files, how to bypass this? I was thinking to upload in chunks but i have no idea how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading large files with Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django)

Comment: ive looked at this tread, someone suggests using django-chunked-uploads i tried the demo, but it upload as a .part file, and to be honest i dont know what that means

Comment: try  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64270076/20875923

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139023/20875923

Comment: so i tried this and ... https://imgur.com/a/LEzAtOM

Comment: Well seems from cloudflare not your django code problem. First approach in my mind, create multiple requests with js. tag it and concat in backend. Create checksum in front and check in the end in django.

Comment: That sounds... i dont know js that well, how should i search on Google to look at some examples? and one more think would this work : https://dev.to/shubhamkshatriya25/ajax-file-upload-in-chunks-using-django-with-a-progress-bar-4nhi ?

Comment: yeah that's fine. there are plenty open source js around no need to code from scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537769/how-to-upload-a-file-with-ajax-in-small-chunks-and-check-for-fails-re-upload-th

Comment: i dont know man, nothing is working maybe im too dumb, is there any way to do this without using javascript?

Comment: Well i think you can increase your maximum upload  size with upgrading your account in cloudflare. Otherwise i  don’t know any more solution since cloudflare would stop it at first step.